# C# - Convert InvocationExpression to BinaryExpression to evaluate left/right hand sides of a lambda

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I need to get the left/right hand sides of a Lambda

ie for (x => x.Foo < x.Bar) Id like to evaluate both x.Foo and x.Bar. The lambda expressions are all guaranteed to be binary

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

var ExampleCheck = new FooChecker<M>(x => x.Foo < x.Bar);

var evalLeftHandSide = EvalLeftHandSide<M>(ExampleCheck.CheckToMake);

double EvalLeftHandSide<T>(Func<T, bool> CheckToMake)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> CheckAsExpression = (x) => CheckToMake(x);

    //use the incoming expression
    BinaryExpression be = CheckAsExpression.Body as BinaryExpression; <<<always null

    Expression LHS;
    if (be == null)
        return 0;
    LHS = be.Left;
    // provide parameters of incoming expression to lambda
    var LHSCompiled = Expression.Lambda(LHS, CheckAsExpression.Parameters).Compile();
    // provide the incoming parameter to the invocation 
    var LHSValue = LHSCompiled.DynamicInvoke(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

    return Convert.ToDouble(LHSValue);
}

struct FooChecker<T>
{
    public FooChecker(Func<T, bool> _CheckToMake) { CheckToMake = _CheckToMake; }

    public Func<T, bool> CheckToMake;
}

class M
{
    public double Foo { get; set; }
    public double Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot convert the Expression to a BinaryExpression as its actually an InvocationExpression... is it possible to get from InvocationExpression > BinaryExpression, or a way to evaluate the left/right hand sides of an InvocationExpression seperately?

Cheers

Comment: What's *in* the `InvocationExpression` -- what's the intended use case of this code? There's no "left hand side" or "right hand side" to that, it's a lambda invocation -- which could be anything, so there's no one obvious way to extract a `BinaryExpression`.

Comment: I would think that you could drill into the `Expression` property of the `InvocationExpression` to eventually get at its constituent parts, but I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: I edited the question to show an example of the Lambdas.... I know the InvocationExpression isnt a BinaryExpression, but once you invoke the example above for isntance, it surely becomes one?

Comment: what you expected? `Expr`  is `FuncToExpression` call

Comment: What is `FuncToExpression`? What expression have you tried to pass? Please add a [mre].

Comment: *Id like to evaluate both x.Foo and x.Bar* this doesn't make sens ... as you didnt provide `x` for evaluation

Comment: private Expression<Func<T, bool>> FuncToExpression<T>(Func<T, bool> f)
                {
                    return (x) => f(x);
                }

Comment: @doozly that is not a way to convert an func to expression (at least so you can split it up into parts), you need decompiler. Also why do you need to do it cause you original parameter is already an expression.

Comment: Guru Stron: x => x.Foo < x.Bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are passing `x => x.Foo < x.Bar` expression the first approximation of what you want to do can look like the following:

```cs
// usage
var evalLeftHandSide = EvalLeftHandSide<M>(x => x.Foo < x.Bar);

double EvalLeftHandSide<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> CheckToMake)
{
    //use the incoming expression
    BinaryExpression be = CheckToMake.Body as BinaryExpression;

    if (be == null)
        return 0;

    Expression LHS = be.Left; 
    // provide parameters of incoming expression to lambda
    var LHSCompiled = Expression.Lambda(LHS, CheckToMake.Parameters).Compile();
    // provide the incoming parameter to the invocation 
    var LHSValue = LHSCompiled.DynamicInvoke(Activator.CreateInstance<T>());

    return Convert.ToDouble(LHSValue);
}

class M
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The comments denote the changes to the original code.

Note that this still far from perfect - it makes a lot of assumptions (like that the type has parameterless ctor, consider `new()` generic constraint or provide the `T` in some other way, or that the left side expression result is convertable to `double`).

Comment: This works... How can I convert from Func<T, bool>?


private Expression<Func<T, bool>> FuncToExpression<T>(Func<T, bool> f)
{
    return (x) => f(x);
}

Comment: @doozly in short - you can't. But the opposite is relatively easy. So try refactoring your code so you should not need to perform `Func<_>` -> `Expression<Func<_>>`  conversion.

Comment: I edited OP to show minimal example... is there a way to go from Func to Expression with decompiler?

Comment: @doozly if you find one) I think I saw some library based on Mono.Cecil but can't find it :-( The better approach could be changing `FooChecker` to accept an expression.

Comment: that is what I did in the end, cheers